# Does NSInteger allow for decimal places?

Tags: nsinteger, decimal, cgfloat

I need to have someone type in a value say "40" and then the app converts this to anther value by dividing by 7.5.  at the moment i've done:

```
    NSString *pCO2 = _pCO2.text;
    float thepCO2 = [pCO2 floatValue];
    NSInteger newpCO2 = thepCO2/7.5;
    NSString *finalpCO2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", newpCO2];
```

and then later, in another view,  the app picks up the NSString called finalpCO2 and converts it back to a number like so:

```
float newpCO2 = ([pCO2 floatValue]);
```

However, when i do this, values above 38 for the initial pCO2 seem to be being rounded to 5 (38 divided by 7.5 = 5.0666) and below this are being rounded to 4 (37 divided by 7.5 = 4.93)

Does anyone know why this might be happening? I want the figure to be to the nearest decimal place at least.

Thanks

Layth

Answer (score 2):

`NSInteger` only stores [integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer), so no it does not store decimal places.  Use a `NSFloat` or `NSDecimal` if you need to store floating point values.

Comment: so how would i schange this? can I use 'NSFloat newpCO2 = thepCO2/7.5;  NSString *finalpCO2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", newpCO2];'  Will that now work?

Comment: No `%d` is for integers.  Use `%f` instead.  See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1

Comment: @shf301 I don't see a `NSFloat`. There is a `CGFLoat` though.